# How to reset time on a Win 2003 Small Business Server Client

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-sbs

I setup a Win 2003 Small Business Server client without setting the correct time. When the user later changed the time on the workstation he was unable to logon. A message is instead displayed indicating that the time on the server and workstation do not match. I tried removing the client from the domain and renaming it but this doesnt solve the problem. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you fixed the time on both server and client machines (also make sure they are in the correct timezones)?

Comment: Time Zone was the problem. Thanks @p858snake.